# Php if(this) change css positon

Tags: php

I dont really know what to search to fix my soulution, I got this php code:

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == false){
  include("mobilForm.php");
}
```

When my form is included i need to position down an absoulte element, ex `top=55%` . But when I log in and the form disapears the element is still positioned at `top=55%` (obviously). Can in php change the position to `top=35%`?

Ex?

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn']==false){
   include("mobilForm.php");
   $("div").css("top", "35%");
}
```

login:

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
$result = $con->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    if (strcasecmp($username, $row->username) === 0)
    {
            $checkPassword = password_verify($password,$row->password);
            if($checkPassword ){   
                $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true; 
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row->username;
                $_SESSION['admin'] = $row->admin;
                $_SESSION['userpic'] = $row->userpic;
                $_SESSION['displayname'] = $row->displayname;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row->id;
                $now = date("H:i");
                $id = $_SESSION['id'];
                $sql = $con->prepare('UPDATE users SET online =? WHERE id = ?');
                $sql->bind_param("si",$now,$id);
                $sql->execute(); 
                $sql->close();
                $con->close(); 
                header("Location:music.php?success");
                exit();
            }
            else{
                echo "<script>
                   alert('Do you even know your password?');
                   window.location.href='music.php?HAHA';
                      </script>";

            }

    }
}

?>
```

Current state  Css

```
body:not(.loggedIn) #searchBarN {
top: 65%;
  }

  body.loggedIn #searchBarN {
    top: 35%;
  }
```

html

```
<body <?php echo isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true ? 'id="searchBarN"' : ''; ?>>
```

Comment: No, you can not just mix PHP and JS like that. PHP could _create_ a `script` element that then contains this JS code. But this probably really rather should not be done using JS at all; you should set a class somewhere in the HTML output your PHP creates, and format the element based on that via your stylesheet.

Comment: Can it be done? Yes. Should you be doing it? No. Rest please refer to the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `class` to your element with `PHP`. In this example the class `loggedin` is added to the `body`:

```
<body <?php echo isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true ? 'class="loggedin"' : ''; ?>
```

And then you can style your element in `CSS`:

```
body:not(.loggedin) #yourform {
  top: 55%;
}

body.loggedin #yourform {
  top: 35%;
}
```

Comment: almost works, but it always says not loggedIn, is it something missing when im logged in?

Comment: I dont know your full code and how you handle your login.

Comment: will it help you think?

Comment: Yes, you can easily add it into your question on top.

Comment: Short question: have you added `session_start();` somewhere? Your `form` is in `music.php` right? And your `HTML / CSS` is wrong. You added an id to your body not the class like my example.

Comment: ah, thanks added it in the start in body and now it works